# NSWorkspace didMountNotification / didUnmountNotification not triggered

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

I am in the process of creating a new macOS application that is going to perform some action whenever a USB device (or other storage device) has been attached to the computer. It also needs to run silently in the background.

For the USB part, I have added the following class to the project:

```
import Foundation
import AppKit

class UsbDetector {

    init() {
        print("Hello from UsbDetector")
        let notificationCenter = NSWorkspace.shared.notificationCenter
        notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(didMount(_:)), name: NSWorkspace.didMountNotification, object: nil)
        notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(didUnmount(_:)), name: NSWorkspace.didUnmountNotification, object: nil)
    }

    @objc func didMount(_ notification: NSNotification) {
        print("Hello from mounted")
        if let devicePath = notification.userInfo!["NSDevicePath"] as? String {
            print("Mounted: \(devicePath)")
        }
    }

    @objc func didUnmount(_ notification: NSNotification) {
        print("Hello from unmounted")
        if let devicePath = notification.userInfo!["NSDevicePath"] as? String {
            print("Unmounted: \(devicePath)")
        }
    }
}
```

I instantiate the UsbDetector from AppDelegate.swift as follows:

```
import Cocoa
import SwiftUI

@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    var window: NSWindow!


    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        print("Hello from AppDelegate")

        // Start UsbDetector
        _ = UsbDetector()

        // Create the SwiftUI view that provides the window contents.
        let contentView = ContentView()

        // Create the window and set the content view. 
        window = NSWindow(
            contentRect: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 480, height: 300),
            styleMask: [.titled, .closable, .miniaturizable, .resizable, .fullSizeContentView],
            backing: .buffered, defer: false)
        window.center()
        window.setFrameAutosaveName("Main Window")
        window.contentView = NSHostingView(rootView: contentView)
        window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        // Insert code here to tear down your application
    }

}
```

To make it run in the background, I have added the following key to the `Info.plist` file of the project:

```
  <key>LSBackgroundOnly</key>
  <true/>
```

When the app is started, it is visible in the Activity Monitor but nowhere else, which is fine. But when I attach / detach a USB stick, the NSWorkspace event is not triggered. All that gets printed to the console is:

```
Hello from AppDelegate
Hello from UsbDetector
```

I am using Xcode 11.5 and macOS Catalina 10.15.5.

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've just made it successfully trigger mount/unmount notifications after moving the code for event registration and the two handler methods into the `AppDelegate.swift` file. But I still have no explanation for why this is working...